# images not showing when using node js with handlebars(.hbs)

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have tried to search for an answer here but nothing so far worked, not many threads about handlebars.
I am struggling to get images to show up on my node app.

I have this on app.js and below that the code i am trying to get image to show up on the .hbs file:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const hbs = require("hbs");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;

require("./db/conn"); 

const SwimmingCollection = require("./models/schema"); 
const static_path = path.join(__dirname, "../public");
const template_path = path.join(__dirname, "../templates/views"); 
const partials_path = path.join(__dirname, "../templates/partials"); 

app.use(express.static(static_path));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.set("views", template_path); 

hbs.registerPartials(partials_path); 

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.render("index");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Listening to the port at ${port}`);
});
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Are your images in your public folder?

Comment: yes in public folder i have created images folder. all images are inside of images folder

Comment: I think you should show the URL at which your image is being requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try below line for Static Path.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html